# Get first event in every spark batch

Tags: java, apache-spark

In a spark streaming app, in every batch, I receive ~100 Objects that contains a time stamp field(long). I want to get the first received object's time stamp. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your problem in the right way ,
Maybe this can solve your problem :

```
stream.foreachRDD{rdd=>
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate()

val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
import sqlContext.implicits._

val wordsDataFrame = rdd.toDF("table")

// Register as table
wordsDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("tables")

// get the minimum value of the timestamp using SQL and print it
val minValue =
  sqlContext.sql("select min(timestamp) as minTime from tables")
minValue.show()
}
```

Please feel free if there are any doubts !

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Indeed this is a good solution but unfortunately not for me. I don't want to use Spark SQL.Yet I found a solution. I will post it as an answer.

Comment: The question was tagged with Java, not Scala, by the way

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I'm mapping to pair the sorted JavaPairDStream with a custom PairFunction that has a field long timestamp that is initialized only one time per batch.

Something like this:

```
private long timestamp = 0;
PairFunction<Tuple2<Long, Object>, Long, Object() {
    @Override
    public Tuple2<Long, Object> call(Tuple2<Long, Object> s) {
      if (timestamp == 0) {
          timestamp = s._1;
      }
      return new Tuple2<>(s._1, s._2);
}
```